# How to sum a column dependent on name of the column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to calculate the sum of a column if the name of the column is "Price" (beacause I can add another column before the Price column).

I have this sort of table:

```
Product Qte Price
 table   4   20
 chair   10   5
    .     .   .
    .     .   .
    .     .   .
```

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this?

Comment: I want to create a macro that can take the result of this sum and send the result in other sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX to return the correct Column:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:Z,0,MATCH("Price",1:1,0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Alternative 1: Formatted Table (ListObjects)

Format your data as table (ListObjects) so it looks like below

[image]

So you can use the table name and the header name in your formula as follows

```
=SUM(Table1[Price])
```

Also see [Format an Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370).

---

#### Alternative 2: Named Ranges

Another alternative is using named ranges ([Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)) so you can use that name in a formula.

For examble select the whole column where now your prices are and in the name box 
[image]
 type `Price` into that box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then you can use it in a formula like:

```
=SUM(Price)
```

If you now add columns before your price column the name "Price" will always stick with the prices data.

Comment: I can't change my excel file. It is automatically generated and i only have permission to browse it

Comment: @KuRuVI In this case the only way would be to use the solution ScottCraner posted.